# Invert the list by exchanging the first and last element, the second and second last, and so on

Tags: python, list, indexing, reverse

So Basically the task is to invert the List by changing the first element with the last one, the second one with the second last etc...
This is what i tried, but nothing happend in the end. Do you have any ideas whats not working here or what different approach i should try?

```
list=[3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30]
y = 0
x = len(list)-1
while y <= x:
    for i in list:
        list[y],list[x]=list[x],list[y]
        y+=1
        x-=1
for i in list:
    print(i)
```

Comment: remove this `for i in list:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the other solutions are good approaches, but if you were specifically
asked to write the logic for inverting the list by changing the first element with last element and so on..here,

```
y = 0
x = len(list)-1
while y < x:
    list[y],list[x]=list[x],list[y]
    y+=1
    x-=1
for i in list:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `reverse()` function:

```
l = [3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30]
l.reverse()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```py
def reverse(lst):
    # Iterate over the half of the indexes
    for i in range(len(lst) // 2):
        # Swap the i-th value with the i-th to last value
        lst[i], lst[len(lst)-1-i] = lst[len(lst)-1-i], lst[i]
        
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
reverse(lst)
print(lst)    # Outputs [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]


lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
reverse(lst)
print(lst)    # Outputs [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: `len(lst)-1-i` is quite a mouthful... could just use `~i`.

Comment: @KellyBundy I think `~i` is quite scary for a beginner, but it's a nice alternative!

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follow:

```
l=[3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30]
new_l=l[::-1]
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. I think this would probably be the most elegant way to invert that list, but im specificially asked to change the first with the last, the second one with the second last element etc. I dont think that this would be a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following will invert the order of a list:

```
>>> l = [3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30]

>>> l[::-1]
Out[11]: [30, 27, 24, 21, 18, 15, 12, 9, 6, 3]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code :

```
for i in sorted(list,reverse=True):
print(i)
```